# Magento Sales Reports not Updating

Tags: sales, cron, reports, magento-1.5, schedule

1. My client uses his sales reports every day and the statistics used
   to be updated every day. We have recently moved to a new server and
   suddenly this has stopped happening - we have to manually click
   'Refresh Statistics'.

   I decided to try and find out what refreshes this data and could not
   find where it's done. We have a cron job running every 20 mins, but
   I'm not aware of a task which is supposed to refresh reports data.
2. Also as a side-note which may be related, we have found that catalog
   promotions are suddenly switching off for what seems like no reason.
   I know there's a cron task that applies catalog rules every night,
   but I would only expect this to keep cron jobs going rather than
   stop them... so I'm wondering if the two issues could be related?

If anyone has any answers to my first question I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like Magento's cron is failing for some reason on the server.  I'd try manually running the cron script and monitor the PHP error log and Magento Exception log, or using a tool like [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) to manually run individual cron jobs and see what sort of errors happen.